# How do I center a form_for form on a page? Rails app

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

This is my form code :

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
<%=f.label :username %>
<%=f.text_field :username %><br>
<%= f.label :email %>
<%= f.text_field :email %><br>
<%= f.label :password%>
<%= f.password_field :password %><br>
<%= f.submit %>
<%end%>
```

I managed to center everything but the form!

Comment: As you center everything else in html, `form_for` doesn't have anything special included to center itself, it just spits out a HTML `form` element in the end. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-center-anything-with-css-align-a-div-text-and-more/

Comment: I think what @Eyeslandic is getting at here is that you would use the exact same techniques as for any other HTML element. Add inline styling or add a CSS rule that targets the form.

Answer (score -2):

You need to center the form with styles. For example:

```
<div class='center-form'>
  <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  ...
</div>
```

And then, in your stylesheets, add .center-form with required centerizing rules. Or you might do that without styles via Bootstrap. With "offset" rules (like offset-md-2) you might push div to center. But please refer to Bootstrap documentation to prototype and understand that.